# angular $watch old value and new value are the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My intention is to watch a value within $rootScope, and call the listener method when value changed. However, I found that if value doesn't changed, the listener will also be called. Is there a way to watch if a value is changed in angular?

```
app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($rootScope, $timeout){
  $rootScope.markers = 1;
  $rootScope.$watch('markers', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('being watched oldValue:', oldValue, 'newValue:', newValue);
  });
  $timeout( function() {
    $rootScope.markers = 1;
  }, 500);
});
```

here is the code, http://plnkr.co/edit/MXIaJKE9UGTMjrreFjb0?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

`$watch` runs when controller created, and then when value assigned, so you need to check equality inside `$watch` function:

```
if(oldValue != newValue) {...}
```